# Import and use Vue.js package from CDN

Tags: vue.js, package, components, cdn

I am importing Vue.js & Vue-Toastify from a CDN to use on a SPA. I only need a couple of reactive components therefore am importing from CDN.

[Vue Toastify](https://github.com/nandi95/vue-toastify)

I am fairly new to Vue and am trying to use Vue-Toastify using the CDN // rather than installing and importing from npm. I have the correct CDN link but how do I import it to use in the .vue file. As I have not created a Vue.js project I do not have a main.js file nor can I use the import method.

Is this at all possible? If I console.log(window) I can see VueToastify in the list of modules but I am unable to use or access it from my .vue file.

Code samples
currently installed via cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-toastify@latest"></script>
```

but then the issue I have is then adding it into my .vue file. Currently I have:

```
let contactForm = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#contact-form',
    data: {
        form: new Form({
            name: '',
            email_address: '',
            message:''
        })
    },
    methods: {
        submit(){
            let formdata = new FormData()
            formdata.append('name', this.form.fields.name)
            formdata.append('email_address', this.form.email_address)
            formdata.append('message', this.form.fields.message)
            axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
            axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
            axios.post('/', formdata)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.status !== 200){
                        this.form.errors.set(response.data.errors)
                        console.log(window['vue-toastify'])
                    } else {

                    }
            })
        }
    },
})
```

I would like to show a toast at the response. This is in a single file with a couple of classes for form and form errors, and vue dev tools are the only thing that is enabled.

Comment: Could you share a snippet of code to show us what you've tried?

Comment: @zcoop98 added sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you cannot use `.vue` file instead you can just use `.js` file.

Since `VueToastify` export the module as a plugin (some libraries might export as a component you can indicate it from exported object, for plugin it will have `install` function). So you have to install it first.

```js
Vue.use(window['vue-toastify'].default)
```

Then you just call it when you want to use.

```js
this.$vToastify.success('some-text')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xzoeg0ru/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have it working as expected. In the event I come across a component library, would you mind giving the example for that?

Comment: @Itergator I’m sorry, I didn’t catch what you said. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dh3szyjw/9/?

Comment: No problem. It is me not explaining myself very well. Thank you for the extra example. You state in your answer that some libraries export as a component. What is the difference in how you would instantiate and use these component libraries as oppose to the plugin (in case I come across a component library)

Comment: Oh ok, this is example I create a while ago https://jsfiddle.net/dtme106y/. As you can see I use `components: { draggable: vuedraggable }` to register locally (you may use `Vue.component` to register globally).

Comment: thank you very much for your assistance. I plan to make Vue.js applications later but for now just using the basic CDN import. I could never really get my head around js - mainly server side here. but I think the way Vue.js is structured/reads makes it very understandable and approachable.